# Probability Density Function of DNS velocity field

Tags: python, fluid-dynamics, probability

I am currently working on a DNS turbulent solver and I would like to compare my IHT simulations to papers. Those papers show the Probability Density Function of the velocity field:

[image]

I would like to reproduce this figure from data. I have access to all the velocity fields at any point during the simulation. I don't understand how to compute this pdf from a 3D velocity field or how to take into account all my data.